# How can I filter data from a DataFrame so that those values that are less than a threshold are 0 and the rest are 1 in Python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, replace, python-3.7

I extracted a subset of data from my original Dataframe which looks like[Test Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzwsj.png)

and I require that the Data Set values be substituted according to a threshold value; for those that are less than threshold = 0.018990814050501657 the entries will be equal to zero and for the rest they will be 1. I tried the following code:

```
            for i in range(0,3):
                for col in new_data1:
                     if math.isnan(new_data1[col][i])==False:

                          if new_data1[col][i]<threshold:
                             r_1=new_data1[col].replace(new_data1[col][i],0)
                             print(r_1)
                          else:
                             r_2=new_data1[col].replace(new_data1[col][i],1)
                             print(r_2)
```

But I got the next output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GYhQ.png)

I get a result more or less as I expected, except that for the last 2 columns I do not get a single column as output, as if I get it for the first column

Comment: Use `np.where(new_data1[col][i]<threshold, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for what you are trying to do:

```
threshold = .18
new_data = [.18, .01, 3]
bins = [int(r < threshold) for r in new_data]

print(bins)
```

[0, 1, 0]

Comment: If you want to replace just set the column back on itself:
new_data = bins

Answer (score 0):

IICU

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'ENSG00000000003':[0,np.nan,np.nan],'ENSG00000000419':[0.013031,0.000000,np.nan],'ENSG00000000457':[0.019190,0.019359,np.nan]})
```

Fill all NaN with 0

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Apply threshold to dataframe using np.where

```
df.apply(lambda x: (np.where(x< 0.018990814050501657,0,x)))
```

Ouput

[image]